# Simple question on linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Question: let $V$ be finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $Rank(T^2) = Rank(T)$:then which of the following are correct?

a) $kernel(T^2) = kernel (T)$

b) $Range(T^2) = Range(T)$

c) $kernel(T) ∩ Range(T)= \{0\}$

d) $kernel(T^2) ∩Range(T^2) = \{0\}$

**MY attempt**: using Rank-nullity theorem we know,

$Rank(T) + nullity(T) = dimV$

&

$Rank(T^2) + nullity(T^2)= dimV$

So both of this imply,

$nullity(T^2) = nullity(T)$(by given hypothesis)

Also clearly as $x ∈kernel(T) →x ∈kernel(T^2)$. 
Hence $kernel (T) ⊆ kernel(T^2)$. But they have same dimension. Hence we have,

$kernel (T) = kernel(T^2)$

Hence option(a) is correct. But I can't able to prove for other options. Please help me out.

Comment: $Range(T^2)\subset Range(T)$. Each item is true!

Comment: But how? $ x∈Range(T^2) → x ∈Range(T)$ ?

Comment: Sorry, but this is trivial. Just write it down.

Comment: Thanks to all of you..

Comment: Did you know there is an `\operatorname` command that allows you to drastically improve your formatting, as in `\operatorname{Rank}(T)` $\operatorname{Rank}(T)$? There also already exists a `\ker` $\ker$ command.

Comment: @chase Sir, thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: Here's a very comprehensive [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you might like to skim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in kernel(T) ∩ Range(T)$ . Then $Tx=0$ and $x=Ty$ for some $y$. Hence $0=Tx=T^2y$. This gives $y \in kernel(T^2)=kernel(T)$. Thus $x=Ty=0$.

Conclusion: option (c) is correct (and hence (d) too).

Comment: @Fred''s sir. Thank u so much. You clear my remaining doubt too.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `\operatorname` command, as in `\operattorname{kernel}(T)` $\operatorname{kernel}(T)$?

Comment: No sir, I am not familiar with that command. Thanks for that..

Answer (score 1):

The option b) is correct, because the range of $T^2$ is a subspace of the range of $T$ and both spaces have the same dimension. The range of $T^2$ is a subspace of the range of $T$ because if $v=T\bigl(T(w)\bigr)$ for some $w\in V$, then $v=T(u)$, for $u=T(w)$. THerefore, $v$ belongs to the range of $T$.

Comment: As I already wrote in the comments...

Comment: Sir but how?  $ x∈Range(T^2) → x ∈Range(T)$ ?  and what about other options?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi What does $x\in Range(T^2)$ mean?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I explained why in my answer. I didn't think about the other options.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, you did not explain it.

Comment: @amsmath $x ∈Range(T^2)$ means there exist $y$ such that $T^2(y) = x$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Yes. And how can you write $T^2y$? I mean, what is $T^2$?

Comment: $x∈Range(T^2)$ implies that $x=T^2y$ for some $y$. Let $z=Ty$. Then $x=Tz \in Range (T)$.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I've added that to my answer.

Comment: But I didn't understand, from this how we get those two equal. and unable to prove other options too

Comment: @Jose sir, after your editing I got option b). Sir help me for other options too.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi You already have an answer for the other options.

Answer (score 1):

The only item that is not *that* trivial is (c). Consider the map
$$
S : Range(T)\to Range(T^2),\qquad Sx = Tx.
$$
S maps between two spaces of equal dimension. Also, $S$ is trivially surjective. Hence it is also injective. But the kernel of $S$ is $Range(T)\cap\ker T$, which must therefore be $\{0\}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `\operatorname` command, as in `\operatorname{Range}(T)` $\operatorname{Range}(T)$?

Comment: Yes, I am. But I am too lazy. ;o)

Comment: That is absolutely no excuse. We have standards on this site, and you need to uphold them if you’d like to contribute.

Comment: I think I don't need no excuse when I write something that everybody can read. Especially because I am helping people. You should better watch out for people offending others which seems to become more and more of an issue here.